# How is the Alternating Schwarz Method used as a Preconditioner to a Krylov Method?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am reading "Domain Decomposition: Parallel Multilevel Methods for Elliptic Partial Differential Equations" (Smith 1996), and I am confused as to how the below algorithm (algorithm 1.1.2 from Smith 1996), **specifically the term $v$** would be incorporated into a preconditioned krylov method (e.g., conjugate gradient) to solve the linear system in eq. (1.8) arising from the discretization of an elliptic partial differential equation (e.g., Poisson). **Is $v$ equivalent to the preconditioning matrix $M$? Is it the vector $\vec{z}$ as shown in the [conjugate gradient wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_preconditioned_conjugate_gradient_method)?**

Here is the algorithm:

[image]

and note that from the book "the application $A_{\Omega_1}^{-1}$ and $A_{\Omega_2}^{-1}$ may also be replaced with some suitable approximate solver". I think this would mean the preconditioning would itself would also require something like its own iterative or direct solver (which seems to also be corroborated by p. 148 of ch.6 in "PETSc for Partial Differential Equations" (Bueler 2021)).

Here is the linear system:

[image]

Based on the conjugated gradient method preconditioned with the additive Schwarz method described in ch. 3 of "Introduction to Domain Decomposition Methods: Algorithms, Theory, and Parallel Implementation" (Dolean 2015), I would think the $v$ resulting from the alternating Schwarz algorithm shown in my question would have to correspond to $\vec{z}$, and it wouldn't be the matrix $M$ just based on the fact that the matrix-vector multiplications would result in a vector.